# updating duplicate table without deleting in sql

Tags: sql

How would you differentiate duplicates in a table without deleting.

I have a table name ANGEL that contains duplicate values. I want to append a letter V to the duplicates instead of deleting them.

Comment: You first need to define what a duplicate is, then you need to identify those that meet the criteria, and lastly update them.  If you want a more specific response, ask a more specific question.

Comment: Table Structure? What defines a duplicate? What RDBMS? What if appending "V" still doesn't make it unique because of existing rows with that value or multiple dupes? Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server, you could write a `update` statement using a `row_number()` something similar to this:

```
create table angel (name varchar(50));

insert into angel values
('test'),
('test'),
('test1'),
('test1'),
('test2'),
('test3');


update a
set a.name = a.name + ' V'
from 
(select name, 
        row_number() over (partition by name order by name) rn
 from angel 
) a
where a.rn = 2;


select * from angel
```

Hope this helps!

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a6757/15/0)